# How to actually build 64-bit Python on OS X 10.6.2

Tags: python, macos

Why?  I want to do this because installation of SciPy recommends it, and I thought it would be a good learning experience.  This question has been asked before (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2111283)).  The preferred answer seems to be to use MacPorts, but as I say, I'd like to understand how it's done.

Anyway, I grab the source (Python-2.6.4.tgz) and unzip.  I read the instructions on how to build a 64-bit "framework" build.  As I understand it, I should run

```
./configure --enable-framework --enable-universalsdk=/ --with-univeral-archs=intel
```

configure runs for a while...and finishes.  When I do make, it's obviously got a problem:

```
$ make
gcc -c -arch ppc -arch i386 -isysroot /  -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes  -I. -IInclude -I./Include   -DPy_BUILD_CORE -o Modules/python.o ./Modules/python.c
In file included from //usr/include/architecture/i386/math.h:626,
                 from //usr/include/math.h:28,
                 from Include/pyport.h:235,
                 from Include/Python.h:58,
                 from ./Modules/python.c:3:
//usr/include/AvailabilityMacros.h:108:14: warning: #warning Building for Intel with Mac OS X Deployment Target < 10.4 is invalid.
```

gcc is being called with the wrong arguments.  Do I have the wrong arguments to configure, or should I set compiler flags in the environment, or what?

Edit:  I don't see any errors in the output from configure...and I see this line:

```
checking for OSX 10.5 SDK or later... yes
```

it ends with

```
creating Modules/Setup
creating Modules/Setup.local
creating Makefile
```

Edit2:  I thought I copied from the readme...

I did!  There's a typo in the readme spec!  My age-related dyslexia is acting up again.  ;)

Comment: Are you sure that your `./configure` terminated without an error? It seems impossible to me to have `-arch ppc -arch i386` in your gcc flags after having used `--with-univeral-archs=intel` in the config flags.

Comment: Wait a second... There's a typo in `--with-univeral-archs`. You forgot an "s"! Strange that the configure process doesn't tell you about it though...

Comment: I thought I copied and pasted from the docs---guess not.  My bad.  Thanks.

Comment: Keep in mind that on 10.6 the Apple-supplied Python is 64-bit/32-bit universal so there's no longer a reason to build it yourself just to get 64-bit support.  And while it's not difficult to build the core python yourself, getting all the standard library parts to build correctly and to install properly can be a bit of a challenge.  There are some post-2.6.4 release fixes for OS X 10.6 support checked in and still in the pipeline.

Comment: Thanks for finding the typo in Mac/README.  I'll see that it gets fixed.

Comment: @Ned Delly:  Thanks.  I was just following SciPy directions and seeing whether I could do it.  Amusingly, having built and installed all the parts, when I built and installed SciPy the install placed it in the Apple-supplied Python, not in my new setup, despite my having invoked the new one to do the install!

Comment: You need to invoke the new Python with the setup.py script or, if it uses easy_install, you'll need to install a fresh copy of setuptools or Distribute into the site-packages directory of your new Python.

Comment: @ Ned Deily:  sorry to misspell your name.  It's not only the brain but also the eyes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to choose an answer as correct, I'm paraphrasing comments above:

As noticed by Virgil Dupras, there *was* a typo in this flag:

```
--with-universal-archs=intel
```

It originates from the file `Mac/readme`, but I should've caught it before posting.
Also I recommend that you read Ned Deily's very helpful comments.  Check out those guys and vote 'em up.

Answer (score 1):

Your `./configure` option is not correct. `--enable-universalsdk` should be set to the correct SDK, not `/`! 
That's why `gcc` got confused, see the option `-isysroot`.
So, check what SDKs you have in `/Developer/SDKs`, and set the correct one.

Moreover, your gcc is called only with `-arch ppc -arch i386`, which do not include `-arch x86_64` which is the intel 64 bit flag.

Comment: Thanks, Yuji.  For the first comment, I'm just following the docs:  specify ``/`` when building on a 10.5 system, especially when building 64-bit code.  I've tried doing it explicityly too (I think).  For the second:  I didn't call gcc myself, and I'm pretty sure if I set a flag in the environment, it will be ignored by configure.

Comment: Actually, --enable-universalsdk=/ is explicitly supported in the configure script.  The real problem was the misspelled --with-universal-archs.

Comment: Thanks for the follow-up comment, and sorry for my misguided reply :p